# Getting rid of funny hover behaviour when changing div width

Tags: css, hover, width

I have some videos with a background overlay and text over them and my goal is having this overlay and the text disappearing on hover. I've managed to achieve this but if I change the width of the div containing the text (class **.project-content** on code below), I get a funny transparency behaviour on hover.

Would anyone be able to help by letting me know how I can modify the width of said div while keeping the intended behavior on hover? Thank you very much!

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="works-content">
  <div class="video-background">
    <a href="#" target="_bank">
      <div class="video">
        <video loop="" muted="muted" poster="" playsinline=""><source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="project-content">
      <p class="project-title"><a href="#">TITLE</a></p>
      <p class="project-description"><a href="#">PROJECT DESCRIPTION</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.works-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px 30px;
  padding: 0px 30px 100px 30px;
}

.video-background {
  background: $black;
  position:relative;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-background:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background: white;
}

.video-background:hover .project-title a, .project-description a {
  display: none;
}

.video {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.video:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.project-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.project-content a {
  color: white;
}

.project-title a {
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 10px solid $yellow;
}

.project-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
 }

.project-description {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('.video-background').mouseover(function(){
      $('video', this).get(0).play();
  }).mouseout(function(){
      $('video', this).get(0).pause();
});
```

Comment: Please strip out the php part and transform scss in CSS and post just the rendered HTML and CSS in a working StackOverflow code snippet otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Thank you, @MihaiT, just updated my code accordingly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k8zg0qxy/ here's a fiddle with your code. What do you mean by `funny transparency behaviour ` ?

Comment: if you get rid of the padding in works-content, the flickering goes away.

Comment: @MihaiT, thank you once again. The "funny transparency behaviour" only happens if I specify a width for .project-content (which I'd like to do). So when I add said width and hover over .video or over .video-brackground the behaviour is as I expected; but if I move the cursor more towards the center of the video - meaning, when I hover over .project-content - the whole video gets a white semi-transparent overlay as a background

Comment: I just solved the issue, thank you all anyway! Instead of hiding .project-title a and .project-description a when hovering over .video-background, I'm now hiding .project-content instead and everything works just fine :)